# How do I install mupen64plus?

Tags: installation, command-line, games, emulation

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux and I just downloaded mupen64plus 1.99.5 and it came as a *.tar.gz file. I found some guides about how to install a .tar.gz file with the terminal but it doesn't work. How can I install it?

Answer (score 7):

You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center by clicking the button below:

[image: Install via the software center]

You can then open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and run it by typing `mupen64plus` and then the name of the ROM you want to run. See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man6/mupen64plus.6.html) for the instructions.

Comment: The link to the Mupen64plus seems to be broken.

Answer (score 5):

To complete Jorge's answer:

- with Ubuntu 10.10, installing from Ubuntu Software Center, we got Mupen64 **v1.5**
  this version **contains a nice Graphic User interface**.
- with Ubuntu 12.04, installing from Ubuntu Software Center, now we get Mupen64 **v1.99**
  this version **does not** get Graphic User Interface. 
  But anyway, install v1.99, and then thanks to third parties, we can get Graphic User Interface like:

  - [cutemupen](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1686384) (in my case, I m not able to make it run on Ubuntu 12.04)
  - [M64Py](http://m64py.sourceforge.net/)

    [image]

Answer (score 4):

Still to complete Jorge's answer, install [Mupen64Plus [image: Install Mupen64Plus]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mupen64plus)

## And create your own icons:

With Mupen64 **v1.99.4**, the only interface is the console interface.
So without third party to get a Graphic User Interace, you can simply **create your own icons** (one per game):

1. Install **alacarte** `sudo apt-get -y install alacarte` 
   and open it

[image]

2. in Menus, Game, **add a new item**
   [image]
3. For the 3rd field "command", **click on browse and select your game**
   [image]
4. Still on 3rd field "command", add **mupen64plus** before the path of your game
   On 2nd field "name", add your icon title
   On 4th field "description" or "comment", add your icon description
   On top left corner you can even select your icon picture, select here a *.png file for example.
   And then validate
   [image]
5. Now you will find your game like this
   [image]

Comment: I don't think alacarte is installed by default. `sudo apt-get -y install alacarte`

Comment: @Grimtech, good comment. I edited the answer to add it.

Comment: The link to the Mupen64plus seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The last version of Mupen64Plus is v2.5

You can download here:

[GITHUB MUPEN64PLUS](https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core/releases/download/2.5/mupen64plus-bundle-linux64-2.5-ubuntu.tar.gz)

Instalation:

> tar xvf mupen64plus-bundle-linux64-2.5-ubuntu.tar.gz
>
> cd mupen64plus-bundle-linux64-2.5-ubuntu
>
> sudo ./install.sh

Use:

> mupen64plus 'Path/to/rom'

example: mupen64plus Mario-Kart-64-USA.n64

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with all methods until I simply added a front end called M64py that can be found at Sourceforge. 
1st Install Mupen 64 plus one of the many ways listed. Then download and extract the proper 32 or 64 bit file M64py for all types of Ubuntu/Mint, in my case Xenial 16.04LTS and it contains a auto deb installer. It was a great GUI front for the Mupen software and worked fine with stock configurations for Logitech and Saitek Dual stick pads. Sound and everything worked well with every N64 game I threw at it. It also happened to be one of the few front ends that worked properly in Windows as long as you stay away from the Dynarec version.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution on ***Ubuntu 19.10***

```
sudo apt install mupen64plus-qt
```

Then you have a 64 emulator!

[image]