# Installed mupen64plus package, but can't see it anywhere

Tags: installation, apt

I installed mupen64plus using this command: `apt-get install mupen64plus`, then I tried to run it from the command line, but it didn't found the executable. Then I tried to look it up in xfce's list of program, and it didn't appear in the list. I also followed the instructions from the first answer of this question: [How do I install mupen64plus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175466/how-do-i-install-mupen64plus) and not luck either.

The package (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mupen64plus/) is installed, but it says in the software center that it only takes 37kb of disk space (which is ridiculous).

Does somebody knows where is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my software center it says that it takes 1,6 MB for download and 6,2 MB for install.

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and search for it to see that is there. To use in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) try:

```
./mupen64plus ./m64p_test_rom.v64
```

You can find [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mupen64plus/) some documentation about this plugin.

[image: mupen64plus]

Comment: Did that, nothing came up. Also tried to run it from the terminal, no luck either.

Comment: Are you sure that you read well [How do I install mupen64plus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175466/how-do-i-install-mupen64plus)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play the game with the mupen64plus software. So I installed it like you did:

```
apt-get install mupen64plus
```

then I download the rom game for n64 (for example Zelda). In the terminal, I unzipped the game and placed it to specific file where all my N64 games are.

Example:

```
unzip Zelda.zip 
mv Zelda.n64 ROMS/N64
```

the on the N64 file I did:

```
mupen64plus Zelda.n64
```

and it opened the software with the game itself.